# Get only inner fields from MongoDB projection in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I've got an object called, `UserProfile` that lives on my user object. The JSON for this object is stored as:

```
'profile': {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'birthday': '01-11-1993',
    'emails': []
}
```

And that is what the `db.users.find({'_id': ObjectId(userid), {'_id': False, 'profie': 1})` request returns. My problem, is that I then want to be able to create a `UserProfile` object with this payload directly, by doing `UserProfile(**cursor[0])` where `cursor` is the result of the request. However, this will inevitably fail because the `UserProfile` constructor expects arguments of `name` and `birthday`, not `profile`. Now, I am currently doing `UserProfile(**cursor[0]['profile'])` but I don't like getting the inner key. Is there a way to project into `profile` and get all the inner fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will answer your query. User `findOne` instead of using `find`. Find return in array where as findOne return single json object and you will not need to do like this `UserProfile(**cursor[0]['profile'])`. [MnogoDb findOne query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

Comment: Your answer shows the direction I'd like to go in by doing `db.users.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(userid)}, {'_id': False, 'profile': True})`. However, the result is still not quite what I'm looking for. I still have to do `UserProfile(**result['profile'])`

Answer (score 1):

With aggregation, you can archive this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"_id" : ObjectId(userid)}},
    {"$project": {
       "_id": 0,
        "name": "$profile.name",
        "birthday": "$profile.birthday",
        "emails": "$profile.emails"}
    }
])
```

The output will be:

```
{ "name" : "John Doe", "birthday" : "01-01-1990", "emails" : [ "mail1", "mail2" ] }
```